# What does this find error mean: "find: stat() error /hgfs: Operation not applicable"?

Tags: find, solaris, vmware

When I use the `find` command on Solaris 10, I get the following error message:

```
find: stat() error /hgfs: Operation not applicable
```

What does this error mean?

**NOTE:** the output from `mount`:

```
$ mount -v | grep hgfs 
/hgfs on /hgfs type vmhgfs read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/dev=140 on Sun Jul 12 07:57:25 2015
```

Comment: What is mounted on `/hgfs`? In any case the answer is probably that it's some kind of special filesystem and the it's best to avoid asking `find` to search through it.

Comment: I suppose look for the permissions applicable for the find to stat on particular directory too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the filesystem that is mounted on `/hgfs` (a filesystem of type `vmhgfs`, the VMware host/guest filesystem) doesn't support the `stat` system call. `stat` is used to return details about nodes on a filesystem and there's no requirement that every filesystem support it.

You can ignore the error message. If you won't want it appearing in the output of your `find` command, perhaps exclude `/hgfs` from the directories you're searching?